# Language changes that possibly break old answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I've seen some code golf languages that still a *work in progress* (functions being added etc), but they have already *been made public* and people are posting answers using those languages.

I'd like to know what the standard practice is regarding *changes to the language* as it's still being polished. *Adding* functionality is always fine (with the [usual restriction](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/can-i-win-with-a-version-of-a-language-that-didnt-exist-when-the-challenge-was) for not winning challenges with a posterior version of the language). But what about *changing* functionality? That would imply old answers would possibly cease to work in the new version. Is that considered acceptable? Should the language designer ensure full backwards compatibility?

As a specific example, suppose a language has function `Xo` for producing the number `pi`.<sup>1</sup> Later on, the designer decides the name `Xo` would be better suited for a new function that is going to be introduced. To what extent would it be acceptable to rename the function that produces `pi`, and change the meaning of `Xo`? "Never do that" / "Try to avoid it as much as possible" / "Only in some cases" / "Don't worry, that happens all the time"... ?

<sub><sup>1</sup>`o` looks like a circle, and `X` is an extension prefix</sub>

Comment: The extent to which you choose to make your language backwards-compatible is a private matter between you and your language users, not an issue which affects the running of PPCG.

Comment: I wouldn't call that "_private_" when the language is made _public_. And I think the question _does_ affect PPCG, that's why I asked here. Sorry if it's off-topic, though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I always just link to either

- a Github [release](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/) of the version in which it works
- if there's no release yet that it works in (sometimes I've implemented a new feature but not yet created a release for it), I just link directly to the commit

That way, the answer is *guaranteed* to always work (assuming Github doesn't go down or something).

Comment: Thanks! That's a good idea, _if_ the changes are made to the language. But my question was more--- how _acceptable_ / usual / frowned upon etc is it to do those changes?

Comment: @LuisMendo It's very hard to avoid such changes in new languages. If you make sure to link to versions in which the code works, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Thanks! That totally makes sense. I'll wait for a while before accepting an answer. Anyway, coming from a moderator, I think this answer probably represents most users' thoughts