# Does fixing an implementation bug renders the answer non-competing?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

In [this thread](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5447/41723), it is accepted that answers that use a new version of a language created after the challenge was posted are non-competing, because otherwise people would implement new built-ins that fit the challenge.

However, it is not clear in this answer (and @lirtosiast comment is not answered) whether or not a bug fix of the implementation of a language is considered a "new version" or not.

It is pretty common for me to find bugs in my own language while trying to answer a challenge.

**Assuming good faith of the user (i.e. that he really intented his language to work that way in the first place)**, is it acceptable to fix bugs in a language's implementation after the challenge was posted, while keeping the "competing" status of the answer?

Comment: For the purposes of PPCG languages *are* their implementations. If no bug-free interpreter exists, no version of the language without the bug exists as far as we're concerned. I think we'd open up a horrible can of worms if we allowed language semantics to be defined by (potentially ambiguous and misimplemented) language specifications.