# Languages with rapidly changing version

Tags: discussion, rules

I have been considering the creation of a [julia](https://www.julialang.org/) based golfing language.
Proposed name: *`Jules`*.
In implementation it would effectively resolve every program into a julia AST,
which would run inside julia.

One feature I was considering was *name-fallback*.
Where if a variable/function name was not defined, it would do a search of the names that are defined, and choose the one that was closest.
eg `prin("foo")` would resolve into a call the julia `print("foo")` function.
And then additional fallbacks if that method threw an error.

This would mean that the behavior of *`Jules`*,
would be defined by the version of the julia standard library it is backing onto. Not particularly problematic -- just up the *`Jules`* version number each time the julia version number is upped.

When it gets more problematic,
is when combined with an another feature I think would be nice to have.
A huge standard library.
As the standard library, I was thinking, **the entire** julia [package ecosystem](http://pkg.julialang.org/).
And having the module loading function be something like
`use Foo` which resolves into `using Foo` to attempt to load the module `Foo` from currently installed packages, but if that fails, then to run`Pkg.add("Foo"); using Foo`, to download and install the latest registered `Foo.jl" package.

Now this would mean the behavior of the language would potentially change each time a new version of any registered package is released.
Since it could add a new function name, changing how name-fallback resolves.
So a new version of *`Jules`* would be created every time,
a commit is made to [METADATA.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl).
This would mean about 10 new versions of *`Jules`* would come out each day.
A *`Jules`* version number, would be something like:
`v<jules_language_version>-<julia_language_version>-<SHA_hash of MetaData.jl`
eg `v0.1.0-0.5.2-d776b19`

With over 10 new versions per day,
many questions will not be win-able with the latest version of *`Jules`*.
See:[Can I win with a version of a language that didn't exist when the challenge was posted?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/can-i-win-with-a-version-of-a-language-that-didnt-exist-when-the-challenge-was)

My current proposed solution would be to have a script that will install the latest version of *`Jules`*, from before a given date and time.
And tell you the version number.
So you could copy and paste the time from the question, to get a copy of the language that is legal for competing.

Does this sound reasonable?

Answer (score 6):

Just yesterday [I proposed doing away with the non-competing policy for newer language versions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/8478). The proposals seems to be getting a lot of support, so you don't have to worry about frequent language updates at all if that new policy does come into effect.