# Answer validility after edits

Tags: discussion, policy

We all agree that using language features implemented after the question was asked [makes the answer non-competing](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/can-i-ever-answer-with-a-language-invented-after-the-challenge-was-posted). But what about after an edit to the question?

Say Bob posts a <s>question</s> challenge. I answer using a new super-cool part of my language as a non-competing answer. I then add another super-cool feature to my language and post a commit. Bob then edits the challenge so that the brand new feature becomes useful as well as the other feature.

Is my answer now competing?

What if I remove the bits that make up the first feature that I actively used in my answer the first time round, only using my second super-cool feature which wasn't implemented/useful before the edit?

---

Can an edit to the challenge make language features that post date the challenge ever competing?

Comment: This sounds like a case for asking Bob to revert his change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### No

I'm only saying this to be cautious, since the "yes" option is prone to abuse.

For example, suppose Bob posts a question but forgets to clarify something important. Since you have knowledge of the question now, you manage to predict what Bob forgot to clarify, and add a new feature to your language in anticipation of the certain eventual edit. Sure enough, someone now points out Bob's mistake, and Bob now updates the question with the edit you expected. In this situation, I don't think it would be fair for your solution to be competitive, since you added a feature with partial knowledge of the question.

Comment: I agree entirely. To me, this isn't any different than adding a feature to a language while it's in the Sandbox (which also makes any solution using that feature non-competitive) - it's exploiting advance knowledge of the challenge to get an unfair advantage.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes,

Edits to a language that were made after the original challenge was posted that weren't useful in the original challenge are competing after an edit to the challenge which makes them useful are allowed.